# Formatting broken when bounty is suggested

Tags: bug, design, user-profile

Looking through my [list of questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/32055/yoozer8?tab=questions), I noticed that the banner suggesting accepting an answer/offering a bounty breaks the formatting of the list, pushing the question item far to the right. Should this reminder be above the question, rather than to the left of it?

Here is a screenshot of what I see (using latest version of Chrome):

[image]